# Does existence of global minimum imply coercivity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

It is known that a coercive function over a closed, unbounded set has a global minimum. Is the converse true ?

The larger context for this question is the following question: Suppose we are given a symmetric, positive definite matrix $A$, we would like to prove the quadratic form $x^TAx$ is coercive. Since $A$ is positive definite, $g(x)=x^TAx >0$ for all non-zero $x$ and $0$ when $x=0$. Therefore, $g(x)$ has a unique global minimum at $x=0$. But, unless we prove the original assertion above, this need not imply coercivity.

Any suggestions on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spectral theorem to conclude that there is a diagonal matrix $B$ with strictly positive entries (the eigenvalues of $A$) on the diagonal with $g(x) = x^T B x$. This easily implies your claim.

For your original question (depending on what exactly you mean with coercive, I am guessing $|f(x)| \to \infty$ for $|x|\to \infty$), consider $f(x) = \min \{1, |x|\}$.

Comment: Nice example demonstrating that the converse is not necessarily true. *How* did you arrive at the example ?

Comment: I took the most simple example of a coercive function that I had in mind (the modulus). Then, I "calculated" the global minimum (at $0$, value $0$) and truncated the function by some value (here $1$, any value in $(0,\infty) would do), so that the resulting function fails to be coercive, but so that the global minimum is retained.